# How should I interpret "off some wall" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

It's a sample sentence under [the entry "skank" in New Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/skank), illustrating the sense "obtain by deception or theft":

> I skanked the poster **off some wall**.

I find it quite hard to figure out what does the speaker talk about. Did he take the poster off a certain wall, or just ripped part of the poster off the wall?

What does "off some wall" mean here?

Comment: Just one data point... I've never heard the word "skank" used in this manner. Is this usage regional? (I speak American English, for reference.)

Comment: @godel9 My dictionaries say it's American slang.  I'm American, and though I can't recall having heard it, I did understand it, so maybe I have before...  No idea on what parts of the US it appears in, in any case.

Comment: OED **skank** *3. trans. and occas. intr. To con, swindle, or cheat (a person).* I'm not aware that it's a particularly "American slang" usage, but it's not common. In the UK the noun form *person (esp. a woman) regarded as unattractive, sleazy, sexually promiscuous, or immoral* is now common (but apparently that *was* originally US slang).

Comment: FumbleFingers defintion is the one I am familiar with. I wouldn't call a poster thief a skank either. I will write to the Oxford dictionary and complain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would interpret it as “off ***a*** wall”. 
The use of “***some***” indicates that the author/speaker is being deliberately, explicitly vague about *what* wall he’s talking about;
asserting that the location of the wall is unimportant. 
Similar: “I drove from New York to Boston; I stopped along the way at some restaurant.”

Comment: Note that when you say the word 'some' when it is being used like this, it is often given a little emphisis.

Comment: Oh?  That's not the way I would say it.